# How do i sum the 3 highest floats and not all of the floats in the txt file?

Tags: ada

So I've figured out how to sum all of the floats in the txt file. But let's say I only want to sum the `3 highest floats` in the txt file, how do i do that? Here is my code for summing all the floats:

```
with Ada.Float_Text_IO;     use Ada.Float_Text_IO;
with Ada.Text_IO;           use  Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Sum_Float is
   
   F, Sum : Float;
   G : File_Type;
   
begin
   Sum := 0.0;
   Open(G, In_File, "FLOATS.txt");
   while not End_Of_File(G) loop
      while not End_Of_Line(G) loop
     Get(G, F);
     Sum := F + Sum;
      end loop;
   end loop;
   Put("The sum is: ");
   Put(Sum, 0,2,0);
   Close(G);
   
end Sum_Float;
```

Comment: One way : keep the three highest, and add them when you get to the end of the file.

Comment: What to do if all the numbers are equal? What if there’s only one number in the file?

Comment: @BrianDrummond How would I save/keep them? Do I need to do some sort of comparison/sort?

Comment: Up to you whether you use three variables or an array with three members. Obviously at the very least you need comparisons! Sorting may or may not be more convenient, that's up to you.

Comment: But in general sorting would be better (if you wanted the top N, for example, not only 3).

Comment: In which case, be aware that Ada.Containers offers a generic sort which you can instantiate for your own array. No need to actually write your own.